# environment variable of "env-cmd" not working after deployment of react app in Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, environment-variables

I'm using "env-cmd" to set environment variables in reactjs App.

> here is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env react-scripts start",
        "build": "env-cmd -f ./environments/.env react-scripts build",
        ...
    },
```

> Here is my .env

```
REACT_APP_ID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

everything is working fine of environment variables  in localhost/local server  , I'm getting variables from .env in app , and even I have tested to create build and run in local server, all is working fine.

**but I'm facing issue of environment variables after deployment of same react app on Azure server. After creating build on Azure server , I'm getting undefined environment variables(process.env.REACT_APP_ID) in my react app.**

even I tried 4 time again and again deployment on Azure , but again issue I'm facing of environment variables in react app.
can someone please guide me?

Comment: How did you deploy your app? Did you use Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx) pipeline? Could you share your pipeline definition? If you try using full path of config folder, how's the result? Have you installed package `env-cmd` on your "Azure server"?

Comment: Any update to this issue?